# Возврат данных из ajax запроса

Tags: ajax, spring-boot

Есть следующий код. Мне необходимо получить в функцию **add_main_menu** результаты 3 запросов ajax. Одним запросом вытянуть возможности нету, так как там разные виды объектов.

```
 <script>
      var main_cat;
      var sub_cat;
      var subsub_cat;
      ajax_get('http://localhost:8081/get-main-cat/', function(data) {
          main_cat = data;
      });
      ajax_get('http://localhost:8081/get-sub-cat/', function(data) {
          sub_cat = data;
      });
      ajax_get('http://localhost:8081/get-sub-sub-cat/', function(data) {
          subsub_cat = data;   
      });
      add_main_menu(main_cat, sub_cat, subsub_cat);
  </script>
```

Пример не работает. Данные выводятся по отдельности в каждом запросе, но в функцию не попадают.

Comment: @diraria пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что тут делается несколько одновременных запросов. Указанный вами вопрос этот случай обходит стороной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var main_cat;
  var sub_cat;
  var subsub_cat;
  ajax_get('http://localhost:8081/get-main-cat/', function(data) {
      main_cat = data;
      checkAndAddMainMenu();
  });
  ajax_get('http://localhost:8081/get-sub-cat/', function(data) {
      sub_cat = data;
      checkAndAddMainMenu();
  });
  ajax_get('http://localhost:8081/get-sub-sub-cat/', function(data) {
      subsub_cat = data;   
      checkAndAddMainMenu();
  });
  function checkAndAddMainMenu() {
    if (main_cat && sub_cat && subsub_cat)
      add_main_menu(main_cat, sub_cat, subsub_cat);  
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: @Никита Пожалуйста. Успехов!